# Angles of a trapezoid with 3 equal sides

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a trapezoid where AD and BC are parallel and AB=BC=CD=$\frac{1}{2}$AD
what is the value of angle ACD?

I tried using the sine law but I felt like it was to tedious, and this question appeared earlier in the exam so I think I am just missing the key property needed for this question. Other approaches and solutions are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Lengthen the sides $AB$ and $DC$. You get an equilateral triangle (Thales).

Another hint:

Take a regular hexagon and divide it with a diameter.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:   let $\,M\,$ be the midpoint of $\,AD\,$, then look at why triangle $\,\triangle ABM\,$ must be equilateral.